# What Causes Jarring?

Tags: waves, acoustics

Hoping this question does not belong in music.stackexchange.com or sound.stackexchange.com,

--

An unpleasant noise which gives a feeling that "something is shaking" is created when a sound intense enough is played in a place where there's bad acoustics. A buzzing noise. What exactly is the Physics behind this Phenomenon?

--

My attempt: Something has to be vibrating, I don't think this is resonance but something to do with Air Columns having Inelastic collisions with walls.

**A more specific case**: Why does changing the shape of the Truss Rod / Fret Board in an Acoustic Guitar create or fix this jarring effect? In what subtopic under Acoustics do they study phenomenon like these?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking about what I think you are, it happens when the speakers are driven harder than they are designed for.

Comment: What you are talking about is Clipping (Beyond one point, Membrane doesn't stretch in the speaker), What I'm talking about is more of an Acoustic Phenomenon.

Comment: A buzz would be the result of material vibrating against something.  Perhaps the truss rod vibrating against the wood of the neck, or a rip in a speaker causing a buzz when flaps of material rub together.  In some cases this can be fixed, in others not.  But some of these examples can be caused by resonance at very low volume rather than over driving a system at high volume.

Comment: My Music Tutor mentioned Bending of Truss Rod too. Sometimes it happens even if there's no rips in the speakers. What about Auditoriums that are not Designed well in terms of Acoustics. I think the place where I performed last year, there was no problem with speakers but jarring happened only when Speakers were at a high Volume and Guitar Mics were turned up. (They literally turned off my Guitar mics because Jarring happened). [It might sound like Im talking abt Feedback from SoundHole of Guitar due to Mics picking up Speakers Sound, but No. I know that it was Jarring and not Feedback]